# How to Eliminate Left Recursion

Tags: grammar

I've read lots of things but can't apply the rule to the following grammar

```
 S -> SS
 S -> (S)
 S -> ()
```

Comment: You should probably ask this on [cs.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the rule:

```
A  -> A a
   |  b
```

Should be:

```
A  -> b A'
A' -> a A'
   |  e
```

Where e is epsilon. So, in your case:

```
S  -> S S
   |  ( S )
   |  ()
```

It should be:

```
S  -> ( b ) S'
S' -> S S'
   |  e
b  -> S
   |  e
```